# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple' will using sql formating in python

Tags: python

I am making a code to add an item to a database, however, I get the error

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

as I am trying to turn the information you get from a tuple when using the fetchall() function in python (i.e. (1,),(2,),(3,) into an int, however I do not know how to do this. Here is the code I am working on.

```
try:
    adding_item_name = input("What would you like to name the item to be? >>> ")
    adding_item_value = input("What would you like the value of the item to be? >>> ")
    adding_item_quantity = int(input("What would you like the quantity to be? >>> "))
    cursor.execute('SELECT item_ID FROM Items_in_stock ORDER BY item_ID')
    adding_item_ID = int(cursor.fetchall()[-1])
    adding_item_ID += 1
    print(adding_item_ID)
    print(adding_item_ID2)
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Items_in_stock (item_ID, item_name, item_value, item_quantity) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    (adding_item_ID_int, adding_item_name, adding_item_value, adding_item_quantity,))
    print("Added item successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print("Unable to add item")
```

I have tried to do this:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = ''.join(map(str, x))
z = int(y)
```

but to no avail.

Comment: That last block of code gives you `12` as an integer.  Is that not right?

Comment: would `y = ''.join(map(lambda i: str(i[0]), x))` help?

Comment: `fetchall` returns a *list* of tuples: a list, to accommodate the possibility of more than one (or no) results, even if there is just one result, and a tuple to accommodate the possibility of each query returning more than one field, regardless of the actually `SELECT` statement being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each query always produces a tuple of results, no matter how many fields the `SELECT` statement requests, so that the API is not dependent on the particular argument to `execute`.

Likewise, `fetchall` returns a list of results, so that the API doesn't change depending on whether the query produces 0, 1, or more results.

So you need to index `cursor.fetchall()` twice: once to get the last (and only?) element of the result, and once to get the only value in tuple.

```
adding_item_ID = int(cursor.fetchall()[-1][0])
```

It's possible you could refine the query to avoid needing `fetchall`. Use something like

```
cursor.execute('SELECT max(item_ID) FROM Items_in_stock ORDER BY item_ID')
```

and then you can use

```
adding_item_ID = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

This will be more efficient as well, as the work of selecting the largest item id is done in the database, not in Python, and only one result has to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
adding_item_ID = cursor.fetchall()[-1][0]  # get the first element of the tuple
adding_item_ID = int(adding_item_ID)  # convert to int
```

you can also use a for loop to iterate over the tuple and convert each element to an integer:

```
for item_id in cursor.fetchall():
    item_id = int(item_id[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much I tried the first one and it works!